# How to select a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

Using that code I'm creating a line from the first touch (touches began) and the last (touchEnded). But to make this shape dynamic (resize and move) I need to select it when I touch it. How can I do that?

```
    shape.opacity = 1
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor


    path.moveToPoint(firstPoint)
    path.addLineToPoint(touchEnded)
    shape.path = path.CGPath

    drawView.layer.addSublayer(shape)
```

Comment: CALayer doesn't handle any touch events. You'll need to make this functionality yourself.

Comment: What you should recommend to do that?

Comment: Probably UIGestureRecognizers will be your best bet.

Comment: yes, I know that. But I can't understand how to check if is already present a shape

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gesture recognizer and pass the coordinates to containsPoint() to see if you are interacting with the shape.